# Matrix dimension in LaTeX

Tags: matrices

LaTeX allows me to write a matrix up to 10 columns only.
But I want to write a matrix of dimension 13. Can anyone help me to write it?

Comment: Welcome! Try `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{13}`.